# return True/False vs return 1/0

Tags: python

Is there any difference between using return True/False and return 1/0? I saw some threads with similar questions for php and other languages, but which is better/more conventional in Python?

Running this

```py
type(True) # bool
type(1) # int
```

shows that they are not exactly equivalent.

However

```py
True == 1 # returns True
False == 0 # returns True
```

and I often see return 1 used in place of return True in functions that are supposed to return boolean values.

Comment: If your function is supposed to be returning a number, return a number. If it's supposed to be telling you if something is true or false, return True or False.

Comment: If your function returns a boolean value, then you should use `True` and `False`.  However, `bool(1)` gives `True`, and `bool(0)` gives `False`, so either will work in most instances.

Comment: @YiBao No, not a duplicate of that C question at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python, `bool` is subclass of `int`:

```
In [1]: issubclass(bool, int)                                                                                                                                                                             
Out[1]: True
```

Hence, `True`/`False` are instances of `int`:

```
In [2]: isinstance(True, int)                                                                                                                                                                            
Out[2]: True
```

and `1 == True` and `0 == False` will compare equal (`__eq__`), and will also resolve to respective truthy/falsy values with `True`/1 (any `int` except 0) being truthy and `False`/0 being falsy.

But you should strictly use booleans when you need such because `int`s are not boolean:

```
In [3]: isinstance(1, bool)                                                                                                                                                                               
Out[3]: False
```

An example of this would be, let's say you're checking the function `is_correct()` to return a `bool` (`True`) with:

```
if is_correct() is True:
```

this will fail if you return 1 from `is_correct()` instead of `True` because `1 is True` is `False` as they are different objects in memory.

But if you were to check the truthiness using

```
if is_correct():
```

both would work.

Comment: Let's say I have a function ```is_condition_true()``` that I want to pass to an if statement. Using either ```return True``` or ```return 1``` would work, but since the function is solely being used to check a condition, I should return the boolean?

Comment: @user3426943 Yes. You can check the truthiness in the example, but for a strict checking you might want tp use `is_condition_true() is True` and that will fail when you return 1 because `1 is True` is `False`.

Answer (score 0):

I will break the answer into two parts:

### 1) Which is better/more conventional in Python?

There is not one definite answer to this part, since it depends on the purpose you are going to use those values for. In general, if you want to check some condition (to use in an `if` statement for example) you will use booleans - `True` and `False`.

If you are going to do some numerical calculations (and of course there can be alot more use cases...) you will probably want to use `int`s.

### 2) Are they equivalent either way?

Well they are not equivalent in the sense of objects, since they are of different types. Indeed this can be seen in the following code:

```py
>>> 1 is True
False
>>> 0 is False
False
```

**But**

The built-in function `__bool__`, which is called behind the scenes, returns `False` for 0, and `True` for any other number. And so, when using integers for equality with booleans or for example as the condition of an `if` statement, the above values will be used accordingly.